# sqeak coming from the front end

Tags: ford, noise, explorer, squeaking

I have a 02 ford explorer, old I know right

I replaced the front and rear shocks about a year and a half ago and everything seemed fine, they went on easy and they only costed near 300.00 usd on amazon for the 2 front ones

But just the other day I started realizing a sqeak coming from the front end, the back end don't sqeak, its just when I hit bumps that I know of

And it does it when I press on the front of the car, the front also sqeals when I bounce the back, could this be a strut issue or could it be a CV shaft, control arm or ball joint

I really am lost, I was thinking about putting lithium grease on everything and hoping is dissipates, but I don't want a sqeak to turn catastrophic

Comment: It's more than likely a bushing which is wearing out. I don't know if there are any grease zerks in the front end, but if there are, I'd ensure all of them are well lubed just to eliminate them. From there, it could be any place where there is rubber or a moving suspension connection. I would *doubt* it's one of the struts/shocks as they don't usually make noise when they go bad (they leak oil and no longer stop the bouncing of the vehicle). White lithium grease probably isn't going to help you. You need to be *safely* under the car and listen while someone moves the suspension.

Comment: If it is a ball joint it will get louder over time then go silent just before failure.

Comment: Do struts have ball joints, I thought I read something yesterday about struts not having joints